# Spring Authorization Server expose rest endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I have implemented an authorization server using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server.
Everything seems to work perfectly. However, I need to expose some endpoints for creating users, getting user permissions etc., so I need to configure the auth server to also act as a resource server.

I need "POST /users" to be public with no authorization, and "GET /users/{userId}/permissions" to require a valid JWT token to be present in the header.

I have tried creating a SecurityFilterChain bean like this, which allows access to the /users endpoint, but it breaks the authorization server:

```
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configureSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated());
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    return http.build();
  }
```

I'm sure it's possible to create authorization customizations for specific endpoints, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've gone beyond the [Getting Started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#developing-your-first-application) experience, the same docs page covers how to [define the same components](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#defining-required-components) that Spring Boot provides so you can begin customizing the configuration. Because of Spring Boot each component is optional. In particular, notice that it defines two `SecurityFilterChain` `@Bean`s with the `@Order` annotation, and also note that the first one includes:

```java
OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
```

Without that line (or copying the code contained within into your own code), the authorization server's protocol endpoints won't be set up, which is why you observed

> but it breaks the authorization server

Comment: Thanks. The issue was that I didn't have the default securityFilterChain defined. Didn't know that it would be overridden.